# Read files without using Scanner class

Tags: java, input, io

Is there a class which does the same job with Scanner(filetoread)?

I know there is the FileWriter class but couldn't find something like a FileReader class?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a FileReader class, here it is at the API:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html

Comment: Well, it's always in the last place you look.

Answer (score 0):

There are many available classes in the Java API that can be used to read and write files in Java: FileReader, BufferedReader, Files, FileInputStream, etc. Which one to use depends on the Java version you're working with and whether you need to read bytes or characters, and the size of the file/lines etc.

Here are some examples (that each print the contents of the file):

**FileReader**

```
      FileReader fr=new FileReader("D:\\testout.txt");    
      int i;    
      while((i=fr.read())!=-1)    
      System.out.print((char)i);    
      fr.close();
```

**BufferedReader (with FileReader)**

```
      FileReader fr=new FileReader("D:\\testout.txt");    
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);    

      int i;    
      while((i=br.read())!=-1){  
      System.out.print((char)i);  
      }  
      br.close();    
      fr.close();
```

**FileInputStream**

```
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("D:\\testout.txt");    
        int i=0;    
        while((i=fin.read())!=-1){    
         System.out.print((char)i);    
        }    
        fin.close();
```

All examples courtesy of Javatpoint